# Sort issue- Orderby non db column

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a database with zipcodes, latitude and longitude. The other database I have has cars with zipcodes of their location. I have a function return the distance between the user location (pulled from ip address) and and the cars location (based on zipcode, latitude and longitude). I want to order the cars by the closest to the user. I am not sure the best method.

I would imagine a orderby(distance ASC), but distance isn't in the db and its obtained on a per user basis.

Language: PHP, MYSQL Framework: YII2

Comment: Please add some code for better understanding.

Comment: I don't want to paste the code yet as I am still trying to come up with the best way of doing it.   I have thought of sorting the query after the filters but the distance isn't in the db. I was thinking of some sort of join table where car.zip = $zipcoderadius['zipcode'], but I am unsure about going about this.    $zipcoderadius - is the return from the distance check function, It has an array with zipcodes and their distances.

Comment: It's hard to help in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this function is in MySQL (e.g. stored function) then you can order by this function fine using say, ORDER BY USER_DISTANCE(user, distance) or similar.

If the function is within PHP code (not-MySQL) then you would need to sort the results after you got the query back.  PHP has various functions that would help you with this:

You likely want one of the user-defined sort functions found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: the function is in PHP. How would I sort the results if the distance isn't in the db?  I can't just sort by zipcode, because they could be closer in distance in a higher zipcode.

Comment: I think you are suggesting after the query result, do a usort on the result where I take the array with zipcodes and distance ranges, sort that for lowest distance, then do a usort comparing the zipcode address with the order for the zipcode on the distance/zipcode array.

Comment: That is precisely what I am suggesting.